# Centering a set of subcaptions

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, subfloats

I have three square images, i want to arrange in a particular pattern, centered onto a beamer-slide.
One big image and two smaller images next to it, which are stacked onto each other, like such:

[image]

But, as you can see, they are off-center and i actually can not get it to work.
I tried different arrangements of subfigures and added `centering`in presumably any possible position.

So, is there something, i am missing? What would be the easiest way of centering this `figure`?

MWE:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}%
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Pictures}    
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the fact that you place two `0.49\textwidth` wide boxes (`subfigure`s) next to each other, and that the two inner boxes (subfigures) are half this width again, and placed flush left in the outer box. Make the second outer `subfigure` `0.245\textwidth` instead, and the inner ones `\textwidth`.

That said, as long as you're not actually adding any subcaptions, I'd remove all  the `subfigure` environments, and use single `minipage` for the two images on the right.

The `\centering` should go inside the `figure` environment.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{To illustrate the problem}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}%
          \fbox{\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
        \end{subfigure}}
    \caption{Pictures}    
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{One fix}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}%
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.245\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Pictures}    
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Less environments}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{1.jpg}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.245\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.jpg}\\
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Pictures}    
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]